# How to remove songs from a playlist

Tags: 7.5, mediaplayer, nokia-lumia-800

Using the built in Zune media player, is there a way to remove a particular song (or songs) from a playlist? I am able to delete the playlist itself, but not individual tracks.

If this isn't possible, is there a suitable workaround, or any indication of this feature being implemented?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't edit playlists on the phone, you can only create a new playlist.